# How to count the numbers of rows with specific value using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, asp-classic

I have a table including 2 columns one with "Give value" and other column with "Take value". I have to count total Give value and total Take value. For Take value it is easy because it is the total number of records in the table. Now I have to calculate total number of Take value using JavaScript/jquery. How do I do it? For counting total number of records in the table (i.e total Give value) as following

```
DIM giveOrTotal, assignrows, giveValue, takeValue
    '############ Convert it to an array ##########
    giveOrTotal =  RsO.GetRows
    '####### Get number of rows
    giveValue = ubound(giveOrTotal,2)

    Response.Write "<table>"
        Response.Write"<tr><td>Currently Given: "& giveValue + 1 &"&nbsp Given Value</td>"
        Response.Write"<tr><td>Currently Taken: "& takeValue + 1 &"&nbsp Taken Value</td>"
    Response.Write "<table>"
```

Now i am trying to count the taken value. Can I do it using javascript?

Comment: Maybe you can add a sample of how the table looks

Answer (score 0):

Add classes and data attributes to store row values

```
Response.Write "<table>"
        Response.Write"<tr><td class='give-class' data-value='"& giveValue &"'>Currently Given: "& giveValue + 1 &"&nbsp Given Value</td>"
        Response.Write"<tr><td  class='take-class'  data-value='"& takeValue &"'>Currently Taken: "& takeValue + 1 &"&nbsp Taken Value</td>"
    Response.Write "<table>"
```

Then in JS loop through rows and sum totals for each class

```
$(function(){

     var totals = {take: 0, give: 0};

     $('tr').each(function(){
        var $tds = $(this).children();
        totals.take += +$tds.filter('.take-class').data('value');
        totals.give += +$tds.filter('.give-class').data('value');
     });
     alert(totals.give);
});
```

Comment: It is showing me take value= 1 although there is no take value. In other words, alert shows take value=0 but Currently Taken: "& takeValue + 1 &"&nbsp Taken Value shows 1.

Comment: I didn't understand why you add one. Seems like that should be removed

Comment: I kept +1 thinking its array and array start with 0. so when I removed +1, it didn't give me any value for take value although i have records under that column. Do I have to do "ubound" as i did to give value? I had updated my question if you check my post.